# Run a VBA code from changing the value of a cell in another spreadsheet with a combo box

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

Saw this question was never completely answered in similar posts so I'll try again.  Starting from a blank workbook I would like to have a drop down list on "Sheet1" but with the input range on "Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4" and the Cell Link on "Sheet2!$H$5"

When a user selects an option from the dropdown list in Sheet1, the value in Sheet2 should change and that should start the macro.   However, I was only able to get a macro to work if Sheet2 was the active sheet.  Is there a code that can execute if it detects changes in a different sheet?  Question 2, do I put the code in "ThisWorkbook" or "Sheet1"?

Keypoints:  Macro caused by a change in a cell in a non-active worksheet.

Thanks!
Art

Comment: You need to put the code in the Sheet which would start the macro if there is any changes in the target range. [See this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213612) for more info

Comment: Worksheets("sheet2"). Range("a1") is how you work with different sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my excel 2013 the linked cell updating doesn't fire any worksheet or workbook event, not even the "Worksheet_Change" one

so I would workaround it by means of the Worksheet_Calculate" event and some additional "tricks" like follows

the event handler is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Me.Range("controlCell") <> Me.Range("linkedCell") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' to prevent following instruction from firing this event

        Me.Range("controlCell") = Me.Range("linkedCell") ' save the current value to be used for future checkings
        Call mySub ' <--- place here your actual sub name along with proper arguments

        Application.EnableEvents = True ' to prevent following instruction from firing this event
    End If

End Sub
```

to be placed in "Sheet2" and which in turn requires the following additional "tricks":

- name the linked cell ("Sheet2!$H$5") after "linkedCell" (or whatever you want but be consistent with it in subsequent steps and in the event code above);
- choose a cell in Sheet2 where to put a simple "echo" (i.e. formula `=linkedCell`) of the linked cell
- choose a cell in Sheet2 and name it after "controlCell" (or whatever you want but be consistent with it...)

that way it should work like follows

- you select a value in the DropDown list in "Sheet1"
- that will update "linkedCell" and consequently the "echo" cell
- the latter will finally fire the Worksheet_Calculate event of Sheet2, which checks the "linkedCell" against the "controlCell" and, if different, runs your sub and updates "controlCell" for following use

Comment: Works great User359!  The macro appears to fire remotely from Sheet1.  Code is simple enough to follow for a beginner like myself.  :)

Comment: glad to know that. a more elegant alternative is having a userform with a listbox appear at the workbook opening, through a workbook open event handler. that way you'd have full control of whatever may happen after any user acting on the listbox, and no need for "echo" or "control" cells